# Shell Script Unix Copy file to a folder with the same structure

Tags: shell, unix, directory, copy

Here is my scenario:
I have an Eclipse project in my desktop in a folder named eclipseProject. Now, I have another folder in my desktop named Prod, this folder has a directory structure for some files that also exist in eclipseProject.

What I want to do is to copy the files in Prod to the eclipseProject folder but they must be copied to the same directory structure but without affecting other files that may be in the same folders, i.e.

eclipseProject folder

-folder1
  -subfolder1
    -file1
    -file2
  -subfolder2
    -file3
...

Prod folder

-folder1
  -subfolder1
    -file1

How do I copy all the Prod directory structure to eclipseProject but not affecting file2 and file3 so only file1 gets replaced.

Hope I've made myself clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gnu `cp` command with `--parents` option.

OR use rsync as:

```
rsync -avz source-dir/ target-dir/
```

Comment: This worked. But now I need to make my shell portable so my coworkers can run it. But how do I get the home directory, I've used $HOME and $(whoami) but I received an error telling me that /Users/theUser/Folder/... is a directory and then it gives me some options to use the command CP. I'm using MacOS btw.

Comment: I have Mac too and `$HOME` and `~` both work fine for me. What is the command you're trying?

Comment: Never mind, its working now. I eliminate white spaces in the variable assignation and that was it. Thanks!